# KDE plasma graphics are not working properly

Tags: drivers, graphics, kde, amd-graphics, amdgpu

So, I have recently purchased a new desktop (CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700x and GPU: Radeon RX470, I had an old Intel laptop before) and I've been experiencing persisting graphics performance issues. I installed Ubuntu 17.10, then after a couple of weeks I decided to switch my desktop environment from Gnome to KDE Plasma, but, to my surprise, all desktop effects were either sluggish or not working at all, not to mention the screen tearing while moving windows around or scrolling up and down. Since everything was working properly under gnome, I just thought it was a configuration issue, but everything I've tried so far has not helped:

- I've tried to tweak the Xorg amdgpu.conf configuration file (I did this several times, many different combinations);
- I uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Kubuntu (17.10) instead, then I tried installing the *devel* version (I know this is not recommended, but I thought maybe some upstream updates could tackle the problem), since nothing worked, I went back to Ubuntu 17.10;
- I've also tried changing some compositor settings (like rendering backend, scale method, vsync);
- At last I tried installing the AMDGPU-Pro driver, but (as many of you may already know) it breaks the whole system.

After all, I ended up going back to Gnome, but I wonder if there's anything else I could do to have plasma running perfectly as it did under Intel, or if this is an issue KDE has when running AMD hardware.

Thanks a lot for your time! If there's any other information tha'd be helpful to solve this issue, let me know and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after a couple kernel updates, so I'm assuming it had something to do with the firmware in it. Since Ryzen is, at the moment, cutting-edge hardware, that seems to be a reasonable assumption.

Well, I'm glad support for it has gotten so much better in such a short period of time!